# .htaccess is not executed when trailing slash is missing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

This is the weirdest problem I have encountered.  I am using mod_rewrite in .htaccess in Apache/2.2.13 (Linux/SUSE), and it appears to not be called when there is no trailing slash in the URL.  I tested by putting garbage in the .htaccess file, and only received 500 errors when the trailing slash was added, but 404 when omitted.  I honestly have no idea why.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

/name fails with 404
/name/ is successful
```

Comment: Please provide your rules/.htaccess; example of problematic URL. Most likely it is your rule .. or some other Apache settings.

Comment: Is there a file or directory named /name/? Also, it seems like you want to match any URI -- if so, `^` as the pattern should suffice.

Comment: There is no directory "/name".  The real issue is that the entire rewrite is not even executed when the trailing / is missing.

Comment: How much control do you have over Apache? Can you edit config files (httpd.conf, httpd-vhost.conf)? If yes -- enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and check rewrite log -- something useful may be there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `/name` is a file name that apache *usually* manages to map to the directory `/name/`, but sometimes this mechanism fails. I've had a remotely similar problem and followed the suggestions to solve the problem according to the *Trailing Slash Problem* section of the [URL Rewriting Guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) in Apache's documentation.

I'd think that in your case you could try to add the following lines (I'd suggest right after `RewriteEngine On`) to your Apache configuration file, if you have access to it:

```
 RewriteBase    /
 RewriteRule    ^name$  name/  [R]
```